# Keep getting 502 on a Lambda request with API Gateway. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I built a API Gateway with Serverless and the first route I made with `allowCredentials: true` won't work.

```
clients-confirmation:
    handler: clients.onConfirmation
    events:
      - http:
          path: clients/on-confirmation
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: 'https://840b1a6d.ngrok.io' # <-- Specify allowed origin
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
              - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
              - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
              - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            allowCredentials: true
            cacheControl: 'max-age=600, s-maxage=600, proxy-revalidate'
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

The user is signed in and I use AWS-Amplify `Auth.post` to post to the route.

I tried to put my localhost on ngrok to have a better feel of a real environment, but it won't work.

My ResponseBuilder provide correct headers I think.

```
export default class ResponseBuilder {
  static create(data, withCredentials = false) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://840b1a6d.ngrok.io',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': withCredentials, // true
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin,Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      'isBase64Encoded': false,
    };
  }
}
```

I use it on every requests. I tried to put the ngrok origin and the wildcard, but it keeps telling me the same error.

Is there something I don't know about the Response of a lambda or a setting that I should add to my serverless file?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If it's returning 502 maybe the Lambda is failing? Check your logs. In that case ResponseBuilder wouldn't get chance to add CORS headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allowCredentials: true` won't work with `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`.

You have to specify the origin explicitly:

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://840b1a6d.ngrok.io'`

also `withCredentials` in `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': withCredentials`
 should be `true`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell that I tried `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://840b1a6d.ngrok.io'`. Didn't work

How do you add "also withCredentials in 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': withCredentials should be true"?